# Python Requests verify proxy is being utilized

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use the proxy feature of python requests library, but the data being returned from the requests being made via proxies is incorrect (page text is still english when it should be the localized language). Is there a way to verify that the proxy is being utilized correctly?

```
agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/XX.X.XXXX.XX Safari/537.36"

proxy_list = {
'South Korea' : 'http://1.241.102.9:3128',
'Sweden' : 'http://79.136.65.150:80',
'Russia' : 'http://77.236.87.175:80',
'Japan' : 'http://153.149.158.149:3128',
'Germany' : 'http://213.136.89.121:80',
}

# Check app availability via each proxy
for proxy_country, proxy_val in proxy_list.items():
    proxyDict = {"http" : proxy_val}
    try:
        req = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':agent}, proxies=proxyDict,timeout=5)
    except:
        print "COULD NOT DETERMINE AVAILABILITY FOR: %s" % (proxy_country)
    else:
        print "%s : %s" % (proxy_country,req.status_code)
```

Comment: Nitpick: `for proxy_country in proxy_list.keys():` -> `for proxy_country in proxy_list:`. Dict iterates over keys as it is. On the other hand your next line uses the value, so do `for proxy_country, proxy_value in proxy_list.items(): proxyDict = {'http': proxy_value}`.

Comment: Well, this answer might be obsolete for sure, but try to catch a simple IP website such as ```https://www.showmyip.com/``` and see if it returns the IP of your proxy, or your own IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to verify whether or not `requests` is using a proxy is simply to enable debug logging.  The `requests` module logs a variety of interesting at `DEBUG` priority, so just do:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
```

Here's my simple test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
res = requests.get(sys.argv[1])
res.raise_for_status()
```

If I run this:

```
$ python reqtest.py http://lwn.net/
```

I see:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): lwn.net
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9098
```

But if I enable a proxy:

```
$ http_proxy=http://squid.corp.example.com:3128 pytyhon reqtest.py http://lwn.net/
```

I clearly see that `requests` is connecting to the proxy, rather than directly to the remote system:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): squid.corp.example.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET http://lwn.net/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9098
```

I see the same behavior if I modify the code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
res = requests.get(sys.argv[1],
                   proxies=dict(http='http://squid.corp.example.com:3128'))
res.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: I'm getting this even when using proxies:`INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): play.google.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /store/apps/details?id=com.bigvertex.petRescueTeam HTTP/1.1" 200 None` do you know why ports are coming through as `None`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ports", that value at the end of the string is the size of the returned content.  It looks like you're making an **https** request there, but in your example you're only specifying an **http** proxy.  You need to modify `proxyDict` to include an `https` key.

Comment: This does not seem to work for HTTPS connections. For example: `https_proxy=http://squid-proxy.example.com:3128 python reqtest.py https://lwn.net/`. urllib3 log doesn't show the proxy name. `DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): lwn.net:443` (using `urllib3==1.26.3`)